# Is Class a Reference Type and Struct a Value Type?

Tags: c#, class, struct, heap-memory, stack-memory

I understand this topic is answered a lot. My question is specific to the way it is said or asked.

So am I right to say, that code written with a class keyword will be on the managed heap and is a reference type, and code that is written with a struct will be on stack and is a value type?

Comment: [No, you are not.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types.aspx)  Value types *can* be on the stack, but they don't have to be.  Regardless, that's not the important take away here; the important take away is that a value type semantically represents a value, not a reference to a value.

Comment: Value types will not always reside on the stack - see here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types.aspx

Comment: It is not a good idea to ask a different question in the title and in the body. In the title, you asked: "Is Class a Reference Type and Struct a Value Type?". In the body, you asked: "...code written with a class keyword will be on the managed heap and is a reference type, and code that is written with a struct will be on stack and is a value type?"

Comment: Please take a moment to read [The Stack Is An Implementation Detail](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx). Though it may be the case, the intended difference between a class and a struct is not that one is on the heap, and the other is on the stack.

Comment: Why do you feel the existing questions/answers don't cover this well-trodden ground already? You say it's something about the way you're asking the question, but I don't see anything obviously different here.

Comment: Cheers all what I am trying to achieve is explain Reference Type Vs Value Type in a sentence. And a big thank you because now I got more knowledge on this topic

Comment: @trincot Please stop editing questions just to change tags for some sort of retag effort.  That's not how retagging works.  See the [faq](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination) for instructions on proper retagging procedures.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used to think like this as well. However, I recently had a nice discussion with *Jon Skeet* (he may provide more details) and he explained me that a `value type` may be kept on the heap as well. The key is **how long will that variable be used**. If it's a short-lived value type variable, it will be left only at the stack. However, if it's used many times, the framework will keep it at the heap to save space at the stack.

IMO, the key difference between reference and value types relies on passing the object to another object or method. If it's a reference type, you are simply sharing its **reference**. If it's a value type, then you are **making a copy of it**.

About the subject of short x long-lived variable, here is the full picture:

> in the Microsoft implementation of C# on the desktop CLR, value types
>   are stored on the stack when the value is a local variable or
>   temporary that is not a closed-over local variable of a lambda or
>   anonymous method, and the method body is not an iterator block, and
>   the jitter chooses to not enregister the value.

Source: [The Truth About Value Types](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types.aspx) (it's also on the comments)

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't entirely accurate. A value type will reside on the heap if it is a member of a reference type, such as a field or being held in an array. Value type variables will be on the stack when they are declared in method-scope. You also are not "sharing its reference", you are in fact creating a copy of that reference (well, unless you specify `ref`, but that is a whole other comment).

Comment: "Value type variables will be on the stack when they are declared in method-scope" is somewhat a "short-lived value type variable". But if you have a static property that is a value type, it will be kept on the heap due to it's long-term existence.

Comment: Saying stuff like "long-term existence" can easily confuse the situation with GC generations (where long-lived objects progress to Gen2). That talk doesn't apply here. A static field is still a class member, so will reside on the heap in the memory space of the class instance (though I forget how static classes are handled specifically). Stuff that goes in the stack is very simply stuff that resides in the stack frame, most commonly at method-scope. References to objects and value types all reside on the stack if they are declared in method-scope.

Comment: I think the talk about how long something "lives" is basically a mild analogy over the topic of where something is *declared*.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth I've updated the answer. If you read the source, you'll see that I'm not creating this terminology, it's widely used.

Comment: Fair enough on the terminology, however, the lacking point is still what is short or long lived. Reading that article, aside from some special cases it boils down to method-scope = short lived, non-method-scope = long-lived. It also doesn't do it to save space on the stack, it is moved because the stack will be popped and reclaimed before the item in memory is finished with.

Comment: It would be great if you try to add the wordings of Mr. Skeet here too. :)

Answer (score 0):

Any storage location (local variable, parameter, class field, struct field, or array slot) of a reference type will always either hold `null`, or else will hold a reference to an object on the heap.  A storage location of a value type will hold all public and private fields of that type (a primitive value type is internally stored as a structure with one field, which is declared to be of that same primitive type; a little bit of compiler magic is used to recognize when special-case code must be used to work with that type).  For every value type there is a corresponding heap-object type which has the same members; an attempt to store a value type in a reference-type storage location will create a new heap object of the appropriate heap type, copy the contents of the value-type fields to those of the new object, and store a reference to that new object in the requested storage location.  This process is called "boxing".  It's possible to copy the contents of a boxed heap object's fields to those of a value-type storage location, a process called "unboxing".  Note that because boxed value types are accessed using reference-type storage locations, they behave like reference types rather than class types.  C# tries to pretend that the type of a value-type storage location and the type of a boxed value-type instance are the same type, but the two types behave somewhat differently; pretending that they are the same simply adds confusion.